# PHP multiple page form validation

Tags: php, html, forms

This is a tricky question to phrase so I'll try my best. I'm a noob and have little knowledge of php so be kind :D

I want to validate forms on a page that is a form handler, so for example my first page with the form (taken from w3schools):

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

So 'welcome.php' is my 'POST' form handler page. But on this page I also want more forms, and on this page I want to validate the forms on it. Say for example some form like:

```
 <form method="post" action='?php echo        htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>'>
 <input type ="text" name="newBalance"><span class="error">*<?php echo    $balanceErr;?></span>
 </form>
```

So i would have some php validation like:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["newBalance"])) {
    $balanceErr = "Balance is required";
  } else {
     $balance = test_input($_POST["newBlance"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $balanceErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
   }
 }
```

...and so on.

Problem is as soon as I enter this page it validate form directly from the previous page and error shows for empty fields on page. 
Is there some way to avoid this or so I need a new approach?

Comment: Store values to Database and then echo them from DB on welcome.php?

Comment: If the validation checks out I'm storing them in a database, I don't want to write to a database  until after an error check.

Comment: Add another submit button with a name to your second form.

Than - first check if button was clicked and than check your condition
 
`(empty($_POST["newBalance"]))`

Comment: Yes I like the sound of this. I already have the second button. So would this be correct.... inside the validation loop have if ( isset( $_POST['Submit_button_2'] ) ) { execute validation}  ??

Comment: Yes its simple way to check which form is submitted in same page.

Comment: You won't need to set the form action if it submits to itself :)

Answer (score 3):

As i understand your issue, you need to check first that which form  submitted in validation snippet.

Insert new hidden field in second form and when you validate `newBalance` field, check if `action` is set or not. `action` field will just set when form2 submitted.

Here is code can help you out.

**welcome.php**

```
// Form2
<form method="post">
    <input type ="text" name="newBalance"><span class="error">*<?php echo    $balanceErr;?></span>
    <input type ="hidden" name="action" value="true" />
</form>
```

**Validation**

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" and isset($_POST['action'])) {
  if (empty($_POST["newBalance"])) {
    $balanceErr = "Balance is required";
  } else {
     $balance = test_input($_POST["newBlance"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
         $balanceErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
}
```

May above code helps you.